# "Go back to the line where I was before hitting [go]/[stepOver]/..."

Tags: lauterbach

During investigation of a hard fault I wished I could jump back to the line in the editor where I was before I hit [step]/[stepOver]/[go].

**Background**
A hard fault is some kind of interrupt service vector which is triggered by e.g. an invalid command. This clears all my registers and jump addresses where I came from. Great isn't it?

Result: "I kind of know which line I was, but precise? ok, again, be more careful the next time..."

Answer (score 1):

TRACE32 stores the register values of the last 256 (by default) halts. You can go back with command `Frame.UNDO` (and forward with `Frame.REDO`). It is also possible to show the stored halts like a trace using the `ART` command group (Advanced Register Trace).